# python webapp2 framework , def func_name(handler):

Tags: python, google-apps-script, webapp2

For which purpose handler class used:

example:

```
def user_required(handler):
  """
    Decorator that checks if there's a user associated with the current session.
    Will also fail if there's no session present.
  """
  def check_login(self, *args, **kwargs):
    auth = self.auth
    if not auth.get_user_by_session():
      self.redirect(self.uri_for('login'), abort=True)
    else:
      return handler(self, *args, **kwargs)

  return check_login
```

actually it is from this [tutorial](http://blog.abahgat.com/2013/01/07/user-authentication-with-webapp2-on-google-app-engine/) :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example you mention is used as [decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics#Decorators). Handler is a method passed to a decorator to be decorated. This decorator is later user in `class AuthenticatedHandler(BaseHandler):`.

Roughly, in your example, `get` method is decorated by `user_required`, thus to understand what's going on just replace `handler` with `get`